# How to work with two layers or more in cocos2d?

Tags: 2d, cocos2d-iphone, graphics-programming

I want to make a game in cocos2d. I don't know too much about it.

My question is related to communication between two layers or more. For instance, let's say I want a layer with a scrolling road and another on top with scrolling clouds.

Is there anything built-in cocos2d for doing that, or any reference link?

Comment: Your question might be a bit too broad to get an answer. Could you try being a bit more specific, i.e. describe with more details the actual issue that you face?

Answer (score 2):

In cocos2d you can add a layer/node to another layer/node.  So for instance, your parent layer could contain the scrolling road and have a child layer that scrolls the clouds.  With this you have a reference to both your parent layer and child layers to work with.  It all really depends though.